# date comparison in php/cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

So I am experiencing a really odd behaviour and any consultancy would be much appreciated.

```
$start_date = '02-07-2014';
$finish_date = '05-05-2014';

if($start_date < $finish_date'){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

In this case `true` is returned. The only time `false` is returned is when the difference between the two days is not bigger than around two weeks.

Moreover, if the finish date is really bigger than start date, `true` is always returned.

Comment: the dates should be in the form 'YYYY-MM-DD' to be compared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you compare dates like below -

```
$start_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("02-07-2014"));
$end_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("05-05-2014"));

if($start_date < $finish_date){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

In this way you would be comparing dates in YYYY-MM-DD format, and it would be accurate

Comment: You could also use strtotime() or DateTime object - as suggested in the duplicate ticket.